# SNMP GETBULK Table COMMAND

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp

I Have a doubt, when we request snmptable request it basically send the snmpbulk request to the NET-SNMP agent and NET-SNMP Agent converts it into multiple "getnext"  requests. Is there any way by which we can detects that all these getnext requests are for the same requests send by me on snmptable request.

Is there any way by which we can differentiate between snmpgetnext and snmpgetnext generated by snmpbulk request (or snmptable request), any session id ?

I have tried to find the transaction id of getnext request by when the number of maximum pdu (number of column in table) requested by the snmpbulk request exceed, the transaction id get changed.

Any help ?

Comment: You've misunderstood the nature of the get-bulk request. It does not result in several get-next requests. In fact, when an agent receives one get-bulk request, it will respond with several varbinds in a single get-response. Please do read up on http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1905.txt, especially the part about table traversal. It will enlighten you.

Comment: In NET-SNMP when we receive get-bulk request. it internally sends the agent handler (which register the table) multiple get-next requests. After responding all that get-next requests netsnmp internally build all that varbinds into single response. I just want to know is there any control block something like by which i can correlates all that get-next requests in agent handler ?

Comment: Aha. I see now what you mean. It was not clear to me from the original question that you are implementing an agent handler in net-snmp. Thanks for the clarification.